# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytesser'

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract, pytesser

I have successfully installed pytessearct(up-to-date version) and the environment path(c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages) is set but when I am trying to use/import pytesseract library it is showing no module named 'pytesser' error.

Here is the program I am trying to run-

```
from pytesser import *
image = Image.open('text.png') # Open image object using PIL
print (image_to_string(image)) # Run tesseract.exe on image fnord
print (image_file_to_string('fnord.tif'))
```

Picture of the error -

[image]

Comment: `PyTesser has been tested with Python 2.4 in Windows XP.` you call from PY3.6 and change directory with a script call. You got more error but this is first !

Comment: Please paste the error as text instead of a screenshot.